# Equivalance Class for ordered pairs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, equivalence-relations

I was given the following question to determine if it was reflexive, symmetric and transitive. Just wanted to make sure my explanations are acceptable or if they can be made stronger.
Question: Suppose $\sim$ is defined on ordered pairs of integers as follows: $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ iff there is an integer $u$ such that $c=au$ and $d=bu$.

Reflexive: 
$(a,b)\sim (a,b)$, then $a=au$ ,          $1=u$ so $a=a(1)$ and $b=b(1)$
therefore it is reflexive.

Symmetirc: 
$(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ then ($c,d)\sim (a,b)$

$c=au$ and $d=bu$,            $a=cu$ and $b=du$

In each I divided by $u$, getting for instance $(1/u)  c=a$, where $1/u$ is not a integer....(stuck with finishing it up)... However I know it is not symmetric

Transitive:
$(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ and $(c,d)\sim (e,f)$ then    $(a,b)\sim (e,f)$

$c=au$ and $d=bu$,        $e=ck$  and  $f=dk$,    so, $e=auk$   and $f=buk$

So, $e=ck$  so $e=auk$ we substitute for $e$ getting $ck=auk$, cancel out our $k$....getting $c=au$ repeat the same thing $f=buk$ given $f=dk$ getting $d=bu$.

It's transitive.

Please forgive the disorder, any help or tips would be appreciative.

Comment: Yes, symmetry fails. If think you did it properly, what is your question?

Comment: I just want to ensure my reasoning may be right, I may be correct in terms of my final statement but how I reached it may be completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove reflexive, you want to show that $(a,b)~\sim(a,b)$:

Since $a=a(1)$ and $b=b(1)$ and $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, it is reflexive.

For symmetric, if we have $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$, we want to check whether we have $(c,d) \sim (a,b)$ all the time.

An explicit example helps, for instance, $(1,1) \sim (0,0)$ as $0=0(1)$. However, the reverse direction is not true, we cannot find integer $u$ such that $1=u(0)$.Hence it is not symmetric.

For transitivity, if $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ and $(c, d) \sim (e, f)$,

- we can find $u \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $e=cu$, $f=du$
- we can find $v \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c=va$, $d=vb$

Hence $e=(uv)a$ and $f=(uv)b$, since $uv \in \mathbb{Z}$,

we have $(a,b) \sim (e,f)$. It is transitive.